# Find <p> tag in a very long text

Tags: php

I have a very long HTML text in which I want iterate id value of a `p` tag in PHP. My original string:

```
$mystring="
<p> my very long text with a lot of words ....</p>
<p></p>
<p> my other paragraph with a very long text ...</p>
(...)
";
```

Result that I want:

```
$myparsestring= "
<p id=1>my very long text with a lot of words ....</p>
<p id=2> my other paragraph with a very long text ...</p>
";
```

As you can see, I can use `getElementsByTagName ()` and regex (may be split).

What is your guidance to do this job?

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning on parsing html try using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) with [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Here is a quick example :

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$query = '//*/p';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
```

Don't use regex, if all you plan on doing is parsing html like this use this method unless you've got a specific reason for using regex

Comment: xpath string you can try : "//*/p" - It gets all P tags

Comment: regex or not ? that is the question... ;-) thx a lot for the example

Comment: Don't use regex, if all you plan on doing is parsing html like this use this method unless you've got a specific reason for using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `regex` like this:

```
$mystring="
<p> my very long text with a lot of words ....</p>
<p></p>
<p> my other paragraph with a very long text ...</p>
(...)
";

// This will give you all <p> tags, that have some information in it.
preg_match_all('/<p>(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)<\/p>/s', $mystring, $matches);

$myparsestring = '';
for( $k=0; $k<sizeof( $matches[0] ); $k++ )
{
    $myparsestring .= str_replace( '<p', '<p id='.($k+1), $matches[0][$k] );
}

echo htmlspecialchars( $myparsestring );
```

And the output/result:

```
<p id=1> my very long text with a lot of words ....</p>
<p id=2> my other paragraph with a very long text ...</p>
```

Comment: They ... just ... never ... stop. Tony The Pony .. He Comes .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454